# basic javascript - referring to an object in an array

Tags: javascript

I was going through one of codeacademy's javascript exercisees and ran into this. The following code is given by codeacademy.

```
var friends = {
    bill: {
        firstName: "Bill",
        lastName: "Gates",
        number: "1",
        address: ['abc', 'def', 'ghi']
    },
    steve: {
        firstName: "Steve",
        lastNAme: "Jobs",
        number: "2",
        address: ['abc', 'def', 'ghi']
    }
};

var list = function(obj) {
    for (var prop in obj) {
        console.log(prop);
    }
};

var search = function(name) {
    for (var prop in friends) {
        if (friends[prop].firstName === name) {
            console.log(friends[prop]);
            return friends[prop];
        }
    }
};
```

What I don't understand is, in the search function, why I need to write out 'friends[prop]' instead of just 'prop'. If the for/in loop is iterating through every property in friends(array?), why do I need to specify again what array each prop belongs to? Why can't I use the following code?

```
var search = function(name) {
    for (var prop in friends) {
        if (prop.firstName === name) {
            console.log(prop);
            return prop;
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Well, this is because for loops in JavaScript are a bit confusing. Check http://stackoverflow.com/a/9329476/60518

Comment: please read the edit i made to my answer - it's quite important or you might run into unexpected errors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`prop` actually is the *name* of the object's property (=key), not the property itself. It's a plain string (`"bill"`) and not the actual object `friends.bill` (/a reference to it).

This is also the reason, why you write

```
friends[prop] // prop gets evaluated here, it's value is the identifier
```

instead of

```
friends.prop  // prop is treated as the identifier here
```

Example:

```
var friends = {
    bill: { ...
    }
}
for (var prop in friends) {
    // prop == "bill";
    friends[prop] == friends.bill 
}
```

Actually, this is similar to (the new) [`Object.keys(friends)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) which returns you an array of all property names of the object you could then iterate on (which perhaps is a bit more intuitive for people coming from other languages).

EDIT: One important note!

Unlike `Object.keys()`, `for in` lists *all* properties of your object, even those it inherited from it's prototype. So if you want to make sure you only get your "native" properties, you always have to [check if it's a genuine property of the object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty):

```
for (var prop in friends) {
    if (friends.hasOwnProperty(prop) ){
         // it's a true property of your object
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`for..in` iterates for the **keys** of the object, not the values.

In case you're familiar with PHP:

```
foreach ($friends as $prop => $value) ...
```

`for..in` only gives you `$prop`, not `$value`. To get `$value`, you need to use `$friends[$prop]`, or in Javascript terms `friends[prop]`.

Answer (score 1):

Think of the variable `prop` as the key in a key->value pairing.

The statement `friends[prop]` is specifying the key named `prop`'s value of the object `friends`.

If you instead say `prop.firstname`, you are actually specifying the property `firstname` of the string assigned to `prop`, which makes no sense, since `prop` is not an object.